# how to return right value in js?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying an angular program but cant return the right value:

```
function facilityChecked(facility, search) {
    var result;

    search.filter(
        function (v) {
            var rtn = (v["facility_Item"]["text"] == facility);
            if (rtn) {
                var checked = (v.inherit_To_Service === 'true');
                result = checked;
            }
            else {
                result = false;
            }
        }
    );
    return result;
}
```

In the code below $scope.parking should be true and $scope.toilet should be false however they both return as false?

```
parking = facilityChecked('Parking', rtn.Organisation.Facility);
$scope.parking = parking;

toilet = facilityChecked('Toilet', rtn.Organisation.Facility);
$scope.toilet = toilet;
```

See also this [plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzSyVG9CTfvXOAFz1prZ?p=preview)

Comment: If you step through your code and/or add a bunch of console.log statements, you'll see that `result` is always false at the point where it's returned. `search.filter()` iterates twice for the values coming from your JSON, and `rtn` is false the second time around (the one that matters) for both 'Parking' and 'Toilet'.

Comment: yes I know you got any ideas? cheers

Comment: I didn't want to assume to know what you were trying to do with the data, but I bet Brocco has the right answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is using `filter` which loops through each item in the array, so it is always setting result to the value of the last item in the array...

so init `result` to start, and if the value is found, then parse it out of the item

```
function facilityChecked(facility, search) {
    var result = false;

    search.filter(
        function (v) {
            var rtn = (v["facility_Item"]["text"] == facility);
            if (rtn) {
                var checked = (v.inherit_To_Service === 'true');
                result = checked;
            }
        }
    );
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is with else part in search.filter(); Actually, search.filter() function is executing for all the Json objects.So, it stores and returns the last object value i.e false".
I think, else part is not necessary, because you taking the values from data.json.

```
function facilityChecked(facility, search) {
    var result;

    search.filter(
      function(v) {
        var rtn = (v["facility_Item"]["text"] == facility);
        if (rtn) {
          var checked = (v.inherit_To_Service === 'true');
          result = checked;        
        }
      }
    );
    return result;
  }
```

Updated Plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/SETl5Zqapsdp8FmB6t56?p=preview